# CMAKE C++ MXE(x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-g++) Cross Compile libCURL from Ubuntu to Windows

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling, libcurl, mxe

I am working on trying to get a cross compile setup for making windows applications using ubuntu as a development platform.

I have WxWidgets working with help of a previous post. I am now trying to get libCURL working. I need to get CMAKE to find the linker options for CURL.

I CAN cross compile simple CURL code using: `~/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-g++ -DCURL_STATICLIB  main.cpp -o winmain $(~/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-curl-config --cflags) $(~/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-curl-config --libs)`

This is great! I can compile a single file! But, now how to do this with CMAKE?

I have attempted this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

SET (PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
SET(PROJECT_NAME "WxWidgets")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32.static)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-g++)
project(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  VERSION 1.0)

  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lstdc++ -static")
  
  file(GLOB all_SRCS
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.h"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.hpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.c"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/**/*.c"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/**/*.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/**/*.hpp"
        )

  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${all_SRCS})

  set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "~/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-curl-config")

  include( "${wxWidgets_USE_FILE}" )
  find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)
  target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ~/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/ /home/kevin/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/include/wx-3.1/ /home/kevin/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/wx/include/i686-w64-mingw32.static-msw-unicode-static-3.1/)
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES} ~/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-curl-config)
```

However, still get the linker errors:

```
[ 25%] Linking CXX executable WxWidgets.exe
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x541): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_init'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x547): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x551): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x593): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x5ae): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x5bb): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_cleanup'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x635): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_strerror'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/build.make:141: WxWidgets.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
kevin@kevin-CF-33S-1:~/source/repos/cpp/aiCamCPPClientApp/build$ make
[ 25%] Linking CXX executable WxWidgets.exe
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x541): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_init'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x547): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x551): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x593): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_perform'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x5ae): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x5bb): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_cleanup'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x635): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_strerror'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/build.make:141: WxWidgets.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

And here another attempt (possibly closer?):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

SET (PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
SET(PROJECT_NAME "WxWidgets")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32.static)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER i686-w64-mingw32.static-g++)
project(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  VERSION 1.0)

  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lstdc++ -DCURL_STATICLIB -static")
  
  file(GLOB all_SRCS
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.h"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.hpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.c"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/**/*.c"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/**/*.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/**/*.hpp"
        )

  add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${all_SRCS})


  include( "${wxWidgets_USE_FILE}" )
  find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED)
  find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
  include_directories("~/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/")
  target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ~/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/ /home/kevin/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/include/wx-3.1/ /home/kevin/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/wx/include/i686-w64-mingw32.static-msw-unicode-static-3.1/)
  target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

this results in a smaller error set:

```
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/src/GUIFrame.cpp.obj
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/src/aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/src/aiCamClientAppMain.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable WxWidgets.exe
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x540): undefined reference to `curl_global_init'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x545): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x564): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x57f): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x58a): undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x5a4): undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x5b0): undefined reference to `curl_global_cleanup'
/home/kevin/mxe/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-ld: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/objects.a(aiCamClientAppApp.cpp.obj):aiCamClientAppApp.cpp:(.text+0x624): undefined reference to `curl_easy_strerror'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/build.make:141: WxWidgets.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/WxWidgets.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

I am now wondering if my problems stem from hardcoding my directories, and if my paths aren't correctly setup and this may be causing issues with CMAKE being able to resolve the files for linking?

If anyone has any ideas about how to implement this in CMAKE correctly, it would greatly appreciate the help!

Thanks you very much!
-Kevin

Comment: target_link_libraries is missing curl libraries.

Comment: @273K I had attempted target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES} -L"~/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-curl-config") but with no luck as well

Comment: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES is not curl libraries.

Comment: @273K, Perhaps, I miss understand how target_link_libraries works, I think I can only have 1 is that wrong? If I remove ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES}, then the WxWidgets lib no longer gets built, and that is no good. I also tried to add the location of my curl.a file, that didn't help as well. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.a

Comment: I don't want to show you the solution, it's better to you that you find it yourself. You use find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED) and you use its result in target_link_libraries. You use find_package(CURL REQUIRED), but don't use its result in target_link_libraries.

Comment: @273K Thanks for the tip! I think I am close! I logged out the directory:
message(STATUS "libCurl Location: ${CURL_LIBRARIES}")
And it does show the correct path: -- libCurl Location: /home/kevin/mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/lib/libcurl.a
so that is great! But calling:
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES} ${CURL_LIBRARIES}) still is no good, I also tried 2 of these calls one with just wxWidgets_LIBRARIES and another with just CURL_LIBRARIES, but still the error, is there anywhere else I can go for more info?

Comment: I don't know. Mauby libcurl.a was built with other compiler settings. Can add only about `include_directories` that is not for libraries and should be removed.